# Отправка сообщений с фотографиями

Tags: jquery, php

Здравствуйте! Столкнулся с вот такой вот проблемой. Хочу сделать отправку сообщений вместе с фотографиями на ajax, все бы шло хорошо но я не могу придумать как можно связать сообщение именно с этими фотографиями ?Была попытка связать их по одинаковому добавлению в базу данных, но фотографии добавляются позже ... Помогите как их можно связать ? Ниже я приведу код самого скрипты отправки зопроса обработчику, и скрипт обработчик! заранее спасибо!

```
  <script>
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive({
        'auto'         : false,
        'formData'     : {'test' : 'something'},
        'queueID'      : 'queue',
        'uploadScript' : 'uploadwallphoto.php',
    });
    $('#addcomment').submit(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadifive('upload');    
         msg = $('.input').val(); 
      if (msg.length > 1000) 
      {
        alert("Characters must be only 1000");
      }else if (msg == ""){
        alert("Please enter a message");
      }else{
        $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true); 
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/insertcomment.php",
          data: "msg=" + msg,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $('#addcomment').after(html);
            $('#listdiv .list:last').hide().slideDown('slow'); 
            $('.input').val("");
             $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false);
          }
        });
      }
      return false;
    });
  });   
</script>
```

Вот скрипт который начинает загрузку файлов прикрепленных к сообщению и самого сообщения!

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'][0];
    $uploadDir  = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $uploadDir;
    $targetFile = $uploadDir . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'][0];
    $photo_root = 'uploads/' .$_FILES['Filedata']['name'][0];
    $fileTypes = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'); 
    $fileParts = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'][0]);

    if (in_array($fileParts['extension'], $fileTypes)) {

        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO album_photo (src,uploader,com_x) VALUES ('$photo_root','$uploader','$com_x')");
        echo 1;

    } else {

        echo 'Invalid file type.';

    }
}
```

Вот скрипт загрузчика фотографий..

```
 $msg = $_POST['msg'];
$uploader = $_SESSION['id'];
$time_now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$sql = "INSERT INTO records (content,date,author,com_x) VALUES ('$msg',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'$uploader','$com_x')";
$qry = mysql_query($sql);
```

Вот скрипт отправки сообщений! Подскажите как можно будет совместить(прикрепить фотографии к сообщению). Заранее спасибо!

Comment: гугли билдер, гугли

Comment: я вам помогу, если посоветую создать таблицу в базе данных, в которой будет имена файлов-картинок и id сообщения, к которому они прикреплены?

Comment: У меня имеется такая таблица, но я не могу добавить id сообщения(в таблицу с картинками что бы привязать фотографии к картинке) которое отправляется одновременно с картинками ... вот в чем проблема

Comment: `uploadifive` позволяет отправлять не только картинки, но и другие данные, так что зачем отправлять сообщение раздельно? Осознайте это и проблема с порядком вставки записей в БД решится сама собой.

Comment: Спасибо большое, не могли бы вы дать какой нибудь пример с отправкой данных из инпута вместе с файлом для большей наглядности ?!

Comment: Всё есть в справке. Вам потребуется: 

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/formdata/

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/settings/

Логика такая: срабатывает событие отправки - серриализуем нашу форму в json - устанавливаем ее как `formData` для `uploadifive` - отправляем - обрабатываем.

Comment: Спасибо,получается что бы отправить информацию из инпута с id pole
в uploadifive придется всего лишь прописать что то тому подобное ?

'formData': {"pole":$("#pole").val()},